# WebView Appium element clicks but nothing happens

Tags: java, selenium, testing, appium

My appium webview element clicks when I run it says it passed but on the screen nothing happens no execution.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyE7Q.png)

I tried this way and did not worked ex:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'x-button-icon x-font-icon x-shown ico-title-save')]")).click();
```

Comment: I see you have too much ids that you can use instead of Xpath, please try to use the element ID instead.

Comment: ID's are dynamic always change ex: ext-element-296, ext-element-197, ext-element-288 only ext-element is same numbers always change

Comment: Is the element displayed? I see x-hidden class in parent element, try is displayed function and try to get "class" attribute to check if it's equal to the one you are using.
And, check if you're in the right webview index and if there are no iframes you need to switch to.

Comment: Element displayed but it wont click I checked coordinates and they are way off origin element. when I set my element to .getLocation() my coordinates are (324, 19) but my origin coordinates from inspector are [970, 120], [1053, 213]

Comment: How would you identify element with correct index and iframe? I'm familiar with webview inspecting elements

Comment: Ok, you need to enable auto review and it is necessary to set to true the setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled property  I think this link will help you out with solving the issue: https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/

Comment: It is  enabled setWebContentDebuggingEnabled this is how I was able to inspect elements through chrome inspector

Comment: Did you try to use javascript executor? 
This example is relevant for the screen sizes: https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/Troubleshooting+Android%3A+Button+Click+not+Working

Comment: I tried this ways: driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element) still clicks on wrong spot so maybe I need to convert from webview x, y coordites to native.